# VS2010 C++ Byte Alignment Issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a weird problem with c++ in VS2010 I don't fully understand.
We use a library (let's call it *LibA*) which uses **2 Byte Alignment** which is set in its **Project Settings -> Struct Member Alignment**. When this libary uses code from another one (*LibB*, which has Default alignment) I get a heap corruption error when deleting objects from *LibB* in *LibA*.

I get that the difference in the alignment is a problem, fine.

But the thing is, when I set the structures in LibA by `#pragma` directives to 2 Byte Alignment, it works flawlessly.

Has anyone an idea what causes that behaviour and how I may solve it? We have hundrets of Headers to be set by `#pragma` directives, and this code to be tested again, which I would avoid if possible.

Why have the option to set the Byte Alignment in the Project Settings in the first place, if it causes errors with "Other" aligned libraries.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you have a struct defined in a header that you change the layout of via compiler options ... then you're in for a world of pain.  When using a library you must make sure that the library and the code using the library were compiled with exactly the same compiler options

Answer (score 0):

It works flawlessly because you fixed the problem in alignment. Is that surprising?

The problem is caused by libB freeing 8 bytes when freeing a struct { char x; int y; } when libA allocated 6 bytes.

Not everyone is using "other" aligned libraries, so the option is there for people who want their structures to use less memory. Some people who use "other" aligned libraries are doing it because they're using other "other" aligned libraries and changing their option to match--something you could consider, instead of editing all those headers. (But I don't recommend ever changing that option, it's only for emergencies)

Comment: I know the underling problem. What I don't get is, what difference it makes if I set the byte alignment in code by #pragma(which works) or if I do the same by Project Settings (which doesn't work). Both ways set the Byte alignment to the same value. In my opinion there should be no difference in behaviour.

Comment: Oh, that's new information, and a new question. If the two libraries are built with all the same options, by the same compiler, including the byte alignment, then none of the code should even know they came from separate libraries once they get linked and I can't believe there would be any problem. If they're built with different options, then that difference is the source of your problems. If the libraries are all under my control, I like to set the options by msbuild imports and delete all project-specific overrides, to make sure this doesn't happen.

Comment: And finally, make sure one of the projects isn't overriding its project-level setting with its own individual pragma on a struct.